# Converting a negative decimal to binary

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

So, I made this code.
Basically, takes in the number, then if negative, converts it to positive, calculates its binary and then its one complement and then adds 1.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int bin[8]={0};
    int sum[8];
    int orig,num,i=0,j;
    int addn[8] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1};
    int carry = 0;
    printf("Please enter the number\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    if ( num < 0 )
    {
        orig = num;
        num = -num;
    }
    while (num!= 0)
    {
        bin[8-i-1] = num%2;
        num = num/2;
        i++;
    }
    for ( j = 0; j < 8; j++ )
    {
        printf("%d",bin[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    if ( orig < 0 )
    {
        for ( i = 0; i < 8; i++ )
        {
            if (bin[i] == 0)
                bin[i] = 1;
            else
                bin[i] = 0;
        }
        for ( i = 0; i < 8; i++ )
        {
            sum[i] = ((bin[i]^addn[i])^carry); 
            carry = ((bin[i] & addn[i])| (bin[i] & carry) | (addn[i] & carry) );
        }

        printf("The 2's complement of the number is \n");
        printf("%d",carry);
        for ( i = 0; i < 8; i++ )
        {
           printf("%d",sum[i]);
        }
       printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I enter the value as 4, it correctly displays its binary value. However, it shows the its 2 compliment as 111111010 ( This is with carry ). Why is this happening? The 2's compliment form of -4 should be different.

Also, is there any other method of converting a negative number to its 2's compliment form?

Comment: Of course you can correct your code, but it would be sufficient to make it work with positive numbers in unsigned variables and convert everything to unsigned by **casting** first. Usual processors today are all based on two´s complement negative numbers.

Comment: Title is misleading. There is no decimal number in sight.

Comment: @harold, I am giving input as 4, which is the decimal part.

Comment: Ok but then `scanf` gets hold of it and turns it into an `int`, which isn't decimal.

Comment: Anyway he's converting asci -> binary -> to a bloated array of int flags.

Comment: Your addition loop goes from 0 to 7, it should go from 7 to 0 for the way you are representing the number with the least significant bit at index 7. You could also maybe clean up innards of that loop, though I think it's technically correct as is. For instance, you don't need addn, it would suffice to initialize your carry to one.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the 1's complement you'll find that's correct.

The slip is, you're storing the MSB in num[0] and the LSB in num[7], so when you're adding, you need to begin at the 7 end, not the 0 end.  Putting (8-i-1) in all the addition part, produces something more like :

```
./a.out
Please enter the number
-4
00000100
The 1's complement of the number is
11111011
The 2's complement of the number is
011111001
```

That looks almost right at the low end, but the sign bit looks wrong, because you suddenly are outputting 9 bits, may be you intend to show the overflowing carry?  I'm a bit confused about your output intentions and I haven't even examined that part of the source carefully.

I won't post the fixed source yet, you should try to learn to debug it yourself by putting in the extra printf's and reasoning about how you input the number initially.

Thanks for the nifty example program, though it could do with some serious refactoring for clarity.  Is it a study exercise?  If so you really SHOULD learn to find errors yourself.

Here goes with the corrections I intended but didn't quite input correctly first time :)

So to check the 1's complement was correct :

```
printf("The 1's complement of the number is \n");
for ( j = 0; j < 8; j++ )
{
    printf("%d",bin[j]);
}
printf("\n");
```

Before starting the add.  Then to fix :

```
for ( i = 0; i < 8; i++ )
{
    sum[8-i-1] = ((bin[8-i-1]^addn[8-i-1])^carry);
    carry = ((bin[8-i-1] & addn[8-i-1])| (bin[8-i-1] & carry) | (addn[8-i-1] & carry) );
}
```

Originally I had typo `((bin[i-i-1]^addn` but I didn't really care about exact results as I knew I had found what was wrong and could explain where the fault lay.

Comment: By the addition part, do you mean in both for the carry and sum variables or only the sum part?

Comment: Think!  You've been given a huge clue and if I just post my code you won't have learned how to debug yourself.  Another big hint... compare how you INPUT to HOW you are adding.. is the biggest most significant bits on the 0 end.. or the 7 end?  Where should you start adding the 1 to?  If you can't work it out, try changing it and making more output to see if it does what you expect.  You really are so close to having cracked it!

Comment: I got it correct, thanks a lot for your help Rob. But, I guess your output of the 2's complement of -4 is wrong. Instead it should be, 011111100. Are you sure your answer is correct, because my program gives me this output?

Comment: Hahah, found the typo.. I have (i-i-1) rather than (8-i-1) in 1 place :)  I was working with the pattern and was just looking for the carry to propogate and thought the output was wrapping the sign bit round, when it carried

Comment: Yeah, but by doing just that, it does perfectly work and just by printing carry in the beginning, it does print the correct value. I don't have to really change it to any other value.

Comment: Also, just wanted to know, is there any other way I can do this? Same question? I am just practising bitwise operators as much as I can because I always had confusion in them. :)

Comment: I'll post what I changed.. I find the MSB in bit[0] rather confusing to be honest

Comment: Well you could use the ^ operator I think, but I need to do something else rather than play with this right now

Comment: But I am using the, ^ operator, but since I have stored in an array, I have to do it bit by bit. Is there any way I can do it directly? Maybe by first converting the array into a single variable, I know you might be busy, however, any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Well as you know the integers are either 1 or 0, then you can XOR arr[b] ^ 1 and know it'll either be 1 or 0. Why don't you change it so bit[0] is 2^0, bit[1] is 2^1 and bit[7] is 2^7, it'll make reasoning about the representation much easier in future

Comment: You could just set the bits in a byte directly.  `uint8 byte = 01` for example, then `byte << 2` is `4` like you expect and odd numbers have `byte & 01` non-zero, even zero.  Furthermore `byte = 2; byte ^=6` sets byte to `4` and `byte =4; byte^=6` sets byte to `2` like you expect.  That lets you divide by 2, by using `byte >> 1`

Comment: Umm, okay. That sort of helps. Thanks for the time Rob. :)

Comment: Can you accept the answer then, so it gets green tick please?  It's way you build up points to pay back time put in on quiet threads.